# reactjs method keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My method is pretty straightforward. It loops through an array of objects and returns the object with the given id in the parameter. Here it is:

```
returnValueToDelete(id) {
    this.state.rows.map(function(value) {
      if (value["id"] === id) {
        console.log(value);
        return value;
      }
    });
  }
```

When I call this method in my render function with an actual id like this:

```
console.log(this.returnValueToDelete("IDThatExists"));
```

It will first print the proper value in the `returnValueToDelete` function since its being called, but than it prints undefined. Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this? I printed it in the render method because I wanted to test it before I put it to use but it seems like it will always return `undefined` since we are printing what's being returned. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is my this.state.rows:

```
rows: [
    {
      id: "name",
      numeric: false,
      disablePadding: true,
      label: "Dessert (100g serving)"
    },
    {
      id: "calories",
      numeric: true,
      disablePadding: false,
      label: "Calories"
    },
    {
      id: "fat",
      numeric: true,
      disablePadding: false,
      label: "Fat (g)"
    },
    {
      id: "carbs",
      numeric: true,
      disablePadding: false,
      label: "Carbs (g)"
    },
    {
      id: "protein",
      numeric: true,
      disablePadding: false,
      label: "Protein (g)"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: what is your `this.state.rows`? Also provide return in `else` case.

Comment: put a `return` before your `this.state.rows.map...`

Comment: @Arseniy-II this.state.rows is a list of objects where one of the keys is "id". See edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the rows hardcoded in the state.

```
 this.state = {
   rows: [
     {id:1, name: 'ss'},
     {id:2, name: 'aa'}
   ]
 };

  returnValueToDelete(id) {
    return this.state.rows.filter(value => value.id === id)
  }

  console.log(this.returnValueToDelete(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you used `Array.prototype.map()`.

In case you want to find a match element, you could use `Array.prototype.find()`, like this

```js
returnValueToDelete(id) {
  return this.state.rows.find(e => value["id"] === id);
}
```

---

> it prints undefined. Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this?

Because you forgot the `return` statement.

Comment: this still doesnt work. I'm assumiing insteand of `value` I was supposed to use `this.state.rows["id"]`

Comment: please provide your `this.state.rows` content

Answer (score 1):

> It prints undefined. Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this?

You are creating your new array correctly, but you aren't doing anything with the result. You can either save it to a variable, and then return it:

```
const arr = this.state.rows.map(...
...
return arr;
```

Or just return the result directly:

```
return this.state.rows.map(...
```

---

That being said, it looks like you are trying to return a subset of your original array. For this reason, you should use `filter()` rather than `map()`:

```
returnValueToDelete(id) {
  this.state.rows.filter(function(value) {
    return value["id"] === id
  });
}
```

and with fat arrow syntax:

```
returnValueToDelete(id) {
  return this.state.rows.filter(value => value["id"] === id);
}
```

---

#### Demo

```js
const rows = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)"
  },
  {
    id: "calories",
    numeric: true,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Calories"
  },
  {
    id: "fat",
    numeric: true,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Fat (g)"
  },
  {
    id: "carbs",
    numeric: true,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Carbs (g)"
  },
  {
    id: "protein",
    numeric: true,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Protein (g)"
  }
];

const returnValueToDelete = (id) => {
  return rows.filter(value => value["id"] === id);
}

console.log(returnValueToDelete("fat"));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems that it only works with the fat arrow syntax.

Comment: @tee, sorry. Fixed a mistake :P